# Add class to .hover functionality on a specific class name - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

So, throughout my entire document, I would like for every single time the user hovers over an element with a specific class name, I would like a class to be added.

My CSS looks like this:

```
.hotspot:hover, .hotspothover
    {
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Class name: "hotspot".

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    $("#hotspot.hover #hotspothover").addClass("bubble bottom");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close!

add a comma:

```
$(".hotspot:hover, .hotspothover").addClass("bubble bottom");
```

Comment: How do I override the other class. E.g. how do I replace the CSS attributes currently associated with 'hover' and replace it with the CSS attributes associated with my other class - rather than adding it.

Comment: You would need to define either the `bubble` or `bottom` classes in such a way that they override. Usually just having them load later will do it, but you could also add `!important` to declarations that are stubborn.

Comment: @artlung. +1 to what you said.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it.

$(".hotspot:hover, .hotspothover").addClass("bubble bottom");

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$('.targetClass').hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass('hovered'); });
```

should work if you are using jQuery 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood, but I thought you wanted it added on hover. This shows that:

```
$('.hotspot, .hotspothover').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('bubble bottom');
});
```

If you want them also removed when hovered off, then change `addClass` to `toggleClass`.

**UPDATE:** Questioner followed up and asked:

> Now what happens if I wanted them to
>   replace 'hotspot' or 'hotspothover' ?
>   As in, for all items on the page with
>   class hotspot or the class
>   'hotspothover' replace it with 'bubble
>   bottom'

I would change it like this:

```
$('.hotspot').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('bubble bottom').removeClass('hotspot');
});
$('.hotspothover').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('bubble bottom').removeClass('hotspothover');
});
```

Now, you could do this too, but if you want to be specific about the actions, doing it as two sets of calls makes more sense.

```
$('.hotspothover, .hotspot').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('bubble bottom').removeClass('hotspothover hotspot');
});
```

Comment: can I just use the class name 'hotspothover' rather than '.hotspot:hover'?

Comment: Yes. What my code is saying is this: "For all the items on my page with the class `hotspot` or the class `hotspothover` - if they get hovered over, permanently add the classes `bubble` and `bottom` to them. Also, if you want the classes added on hover, and removed on un-hover, use `toggleClass`

Comment: Now what happens if I wanted them to replace 'hotspot' or 'hotspothover' ? As in, for all items on the page with class hotspot or the class 'hotspothover' replace it with 'bubble bottom'.