# How to call a class/id from hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an small ecommerce site with a product grid view containing:

```
.product-image
.product-price
.product-name
```

And in the main product page, it contains same classes as the above, plus:

```
.product-discount
```

What I am trying to do on the grid view is to show the `.product-discount` tag when the `.product-image` is hovered over.

I just want to know how to hover a class tag. I have tried:

```
.product-image:hover { something that would call the .product-discount; }
```

[image]

Comment: this link may help you : [link-class hover][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769611/add-class-to-hover-functionality-on-a-specific-class-name-jquery

Comment: If the `.product-discount` is a child of `.product-image` you could do `.product-image:hover .product-discount { display:block; }`

Answer (score 2):

A pseudo-class doesn't have to be the trailing part. So this is valid and should work:

```
.product-image .product-discount { visibility:hidden; } /* make sure it takes up space (for whatever reason) */
.product-image:hover .product-discount{ visibility:visible; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery('.product-image').bind('hover', function(){ 
    jQuery('.product-discount').show(); 
}
```